# Loop through objects and change their values

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-models

I have my model set up so that when a liquor is added to a store, it gives it it's own in-store ID based on the count. I've called this the SPI. The addition function works fine, it properly assigns the correct SPI. But I'm having trouble with the delete function. When an object is deleted from the table, I need it to loop through the remaining objects and set their SPI to one less. However I keep getting an error `StoreLiquor matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'StoreLiquorID': 7, 'storeID': <Store: test store>}` Am I not doing the query correctly?

The models:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    StoreID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    StoreName = models.CharField('Store Name', max_length=30)
    (other things here too but probably not necessary for this case)

class StoreLiquor(models.Model):
    StoreLiquorID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    liquorID = models.ForeignKey(Liquor)
    storeID = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    StorePrice = models.DecimalField('Store Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    SPI = models.PositiveIntegerField('SPI', max_length=10)
```

The view:

```
def delete(request, liquor_id, store_id):
    storeID = Store.objects.get(StoreID=store_id)
    StLiquor = StoreLiquor.objects.get(storeID=store_id, StoreLiquorID=liquor_id)
    LiqSPI = StLiquor.SPI
    SPIcount = StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=store_id).count()

    for newSPI in range(LiqSPI, SPIcount):
        newStLiquor = StoreLiquor.objects.get(storeID=storeID, StoreLiquorID=newSPI)
        newStLiquor.SPI = newSPI-1

    StLiquor.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for` loop, use queryset.update with [`django.db.models.F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields):

```
from django.db.models import F

...

StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=storeID, SPI__gt=LiqSPI).update(SPI=F('SPI')-1)
```